# How to remove substring from string in pandas column that contain both numbers and chars

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I know that if we have strings like this

```
May21
James
Adi22
Hello
Girl90
zt411
```

We can use regex with `\d+` to remove all the numbers. But how would I also remove the entire string if the string also contains characters. Thus the only thing that would be returned in the latter above would be James and Hello?

I can do this for just one string:

```
c = 'xterm has been replaced new mac 008064c79202'
c = ' '.join(w for w in c.split() if not any(x.isdigit() for x in w))
c
```

How would I apply this across an entire dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your function to a column as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['May21', 'James', 'Adi22', 'Hello', 'Girl90', 'zt411'], columns=['word'])

def remove_semi_nums(c):
    return ' '.join(w for w in c.split() if not any(x.isdigit() for x in w))

# option A: list comprehension (I like this better)
df['word'] = [remove_semi_nums(x) for x in df.word]

# option B: use `apply` which I don't recommend for big data sets because it's slow. (Also cumbersome to use for functions that use multiple columns as args)
df['word'] = df['word'].apply(remove_semi_nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression like

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+\d|\d+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\d]+$
```

with [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MQjbvo/1). Details:

- `^` (implicit in `.match`): start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z]+\d|\d+[A-Za-z])` - either one or more letters and then a digit or one or more digits and then a letter
- `[A-Za-z\d]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the Pandas test:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['May21', 'James', 'Adi22', 'Hello', 'Girl90', 'zt411'], columns=['word'])
df[df['word'].str.match(r'(?:[A-Za-z]+\d|\d+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\d]+$')] = ""
>>> df
    word
0       
1  James
2       
3  Hello
4       
5
```